# Extract image from echoed block

Tags: magento2, blocks, image, static-block

Is it possible to echo a image / images from a static block? So something like this:

```
echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId($optionText)->getImages()
```

Comment: No, you can not do that with core CMS Block module, but for this, you have to override  Magento's core `Magento\Cms\Block\Block` file.

Comment: Why do you want to do so ?

Comment: In phtml file you can shape it as you want.

Comment: @ManishGoswami due to a functionality I have to make for a webshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually used the following:

```
$img = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block-id')->toHtml();

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($img);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");

echo "<img src=$src>";
```

This only works when your block contains only one image tho, but fine for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Static block contains html thats why you cannot fetch images from static block in this way. If you want to fetch the images from that html then you can try the below code:

```
$html = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('your_identifier')->toHtml();
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$html, $images);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($images);
echo '</pre>';
```

You will get all the images in your $images variable.

Comment: This unfortunately returns an empty array.

Comment: yes, because of no image tag found in `$html`.

Comment: @kunj unfortunately, there is an image tag in my block defined in `$html`

Comment: Can you send HTML?

Comment: This code is working fine for me but it will not work for background images. Please ensure you are not using background images instead of <img src=""/>